# Autoexpand and Autoshirink of div?

Tags: css-float, css

I have rows of photo of same size shown, when you dont have sufficient number of photos in a row, the photo should expand in width to occupy full space. There can 3 inner divs or 4 inner divs.

```
// CSS Section

    .cont {
    position : absolute;
    background : #E4EDF7;
    border : 1px solid grey;
    height: 200px;
    width:400px;
    }   

    .ibox {
    float: left;
    background : green;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;   
    }

// HTML Markup

    <div class="cont"> 
        <div class="ibox"></div>
        <div class="ibox"></div>
        <div class="ibox"></div>
        <div class="ibox"></div>
        <div class="ibox"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you using a server-side language to crete the list of images, or is it all hard-coded html? If you're using a server-side language you can do a bit of maths to work out what % of the window you can use for each image.

Comment: i need a solution, need not be from front end alone, it can be combination of front end and back end aswell.

Comment: I suppose you can get the amount of elements with the class .ibox and then divide their parent's (ie cont) width by the amount. To be sure to neglect padding, margin and border you should apply a box-sizing: border-box; though.

Comment: Curious, if there can "3 inner divs or 4 inner divs" why your html markup above shows 5?

Comment: What kind of browser do you need to support and any target platform?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did a little experimentation and came up with a quick solution to your autosizing issue:

```
.cont { 
    position : absolute; 
    background : #E4EDF7; 
    border : 1px solid grey; 
    height: 200px; 
    width:400px; 
        display:table;
    }
```

within the "cont" class just add the last bit "display:table;" and the outer box should resize 
to the added contents.

Comment: I'm not seeing any expansion occurring just by adding `display: table`. See http://jsfiddle.net/zh6PZ/10/ (Firefox). Was there something else you did in your experimentation?

Comment: @ScottS I checked the link you sent me and added an additional bit. See http://jsfiddle.net/zh6PZ/16/

Comment: You're still not showing me a difference using `display:table` between 4 cells wide and 3 cells wide, which is what he is requesting. Instead of populating a bunch of cells via javascript, show me a single row with 3 and another with 4 and how you would expand the width of the 3 to fill the same horizontal space as the 4. I do think there is a way to do it with `display: table`, but I have not yet seen you give me a working example of it. If you can, I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: @ScottS I looked into your previous comment and came up with this, see http://jsfiddle.net/zh6PZ/24/ . If I understood you correctly, you wanted to know how I would adjust the width to accommodate 4 cells vs 3 cells respectively.

Comment: Not quite. What I wanted to see was a cell "automatically" expand in the 3 cell to _fill_ the space of a four cell width. The OP desired that "when you dont [sic] have sufficient number of photos in a row [i.e. when it is 3 photos], the _photo_ [emphasis added] should expand in width to occupy full space." Basically, using `display: table`, can you get it to look something like either of my examples (http://jsfiddle.net/zh6PZ/19/ or http://jsfiddle.net/zh6PZ/17/)? Which the OP wanted I don't know, as he never did accept anyone's answer or comment further after answers were given.

Answer (score 2):

**Brains911** made a good point as to confusion on what you actually want. I interpreted your "the photo" as 1 photo (the last) expanding in width, which is the original answer below. However, if you want "the photos" (plural, all 3) to expand, then there is a CSS3 answer that I have added below.

### Original Answer (CSS2: Last photo only expands)

Add this below your `ibox` css:

```
.ibox:first-child + .ibox + .ibox:last-child {
   width: 210px; /* 2 x width + 2 x margin */
}
```

It will only target the `ibox` and change the width if there are 3 instead of 4. [**See the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zh6PZ/17/), where I had to modify the `width` of your `cont` to accommodate your margins, but you should get the idea.

### Additional Answer (CSS3: All 3 photos expand)

Change your standard width in your `.ibox` definition to what you want for 3 photos ([**in my example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zh6PZ/19/) I used `137px`), then add this css for the 4 photo scenario:

```
.ibox:nth-last-of-type(4),
.ibox:nth-last-of-type(4) ~ .ibox {
    width: 100px;
 }
```

It counts backwards from the end and if there are 4, it will trigger the styling for 4 instead of the default 3.

Comment: Nice work! Never used nth-last-of-type. Cool that it goes backwards. Gets a vote up.

Answer (score 2):

Question is a little confusing but I'm assuming you would want all photos in a row to expand equally to fill the row if there are only 3 rather than 4...

So.. not knowing the exact number of .ibox divs (3 or 4), there is no easy/reliable way to achieve this with css alone (that i know of) unless you can use some css3 - [The CSS 3 Flexible Box Model](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/) - which may not be an option if you require older browser compatibility.

With a bit of jquery it would be fairly quick e.g.

```
var container = $('.cont'), 
    iboxCount = container.find('.ibox').length,
    photoWidth = container.width()/iboxCount; //TODO: adjust for margin/padding

container.find('.ibox').css('width',photoWidth);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on being "confusing," you certainly interpreted it differently than I did, so I updated my answer to accommodate either reading. I did use CSS3 to do the equal widths, but not with the flexible box model that you mentioned in your answer.